# How to get average of a row, insert it to the database table and fetch it out

Tags: php, css, mysql

I have this code for printing out the values of my database table and I want it to have the average

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>

<?php 
include_once('../config/dbcon.php'); 
$query="select * from testeval"; 
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query); 
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

    <head>

    <style>
    table, th, td{
        border: 3px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th{
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    td {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .title {
            max-width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
    }
    table {
        text-align= center;
         border: 1px;
        max-width= 1000px;
         line-height= 40px;
    }
    </style>

    </head> 

    <body class = "title"> 
    <table> 
    <form>
    <tr> 
    
        <th colspan="4"><h2>Evaluation Record</h2></th> 
        </tr> 

        <?php 

            
            while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        { 
        ?> 
            
            <tr>
              <th> ID: </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Name: </th>
              <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 1. Formulates/adopts objectives of the syllabus course learning outcomes. </th>
              <td><?php echo $row['q1']; ?> </td>
            <tr>
              <th> 2. Selects content and prepares appropriate instructional materials/teaching aids.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q2']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 3. Selects appropriate teaching methods/strategies.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q3']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 4. Relates new lesson with previous knowledge/skills.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q4']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 5. Conveys ideas clearly.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q5']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 6. Utilizes the art of questioning to develop higher level of thinking.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q6']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 7. Ensures students participation. </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q7']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 8. Shows mastery of the subject matter.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q8']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 9. Utilizes the blackboard or the learning management system of the college.  </th>
              <td><?php echo $row['q8']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 10. Creates assessments that are aligned with the syllabus course learning outcomes  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q10']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 11. Evaluates the attainment of the syllabus course learning outcomest.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q11']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 12. Maintains orderly classroom that is conducive to learning.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q12']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 13. Decisiveness  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q13']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 14. Honesty / Integrity  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q14']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 15. Dedication / Commitment  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q15']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 16. Initiative / Resourcefulness  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q16']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 17. Courtesy  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q17']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 18. Human Relations  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q18']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 19. Leadership  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q19']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 20. Stress Toleranc  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q20']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 21. Fairness / Justice  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q21']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 22. Proper Attire / Good Grooming  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q22']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Average:   </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['ave']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Remarks:  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['message']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> <center> ------------------------------------------------------ </center> </th> 
              <td> <center> ------------------------------------------------------ </center> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> <center> ------------------------------------------------------ </center> </th> 
              <td> <center> ------------------------------------------------------ </center> </td>
            </tr>

              
        </tr> 
        
        
        
    
        </tr> 
        </form>
    <?php 
               } 
          ?> 

    </table> 
    </body> 
    </html>

<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

My database table looks the picture attached

How to add up all the values of the whole row with all columns
then fetch it out so I can print it out along with the other inside the code I have
I have searched everywhere and all I see is getting the average of the column of a database table so I was wondering how can I add up all the values of column q1 to q22 of a row.

Comment: should it be calculated server-sided or user-sided? With the current format, it should be done user-sided with JS. If you want to calculate it server-sided with PHP then you should change the code entirely and create the table dynamically from an array or object that you can use to calculate the average directly from. PS: `<center>` is obsolete and should not be used in HTML5 anymore.

Comment: @tacoshy what should i do if it is user-sided calculation I'm not that familiar with JS

Answer (score 0):

Add a total variable outside the while loop:

```
$total = 0;
```

Inside the loop:

```
$total += $row['q1'] + $row['q2'] + $row['q3'] + $row['q4'] + $row['q5'] + $row['q6'] + $row['q7'] + $row['q8'] + $row['q9'] + $row['q10'] + $row['q11'] + $row['q12'] + $row['q13'] + $row['q14'] + $row['q15'] + $row['q16'] + $row['q17'] + $row['q18'] + $row['q19'] + $row['q20'] + $row['q21'] + $row['q22'];
```

After the while loop:

```
$average = $total / 22;
```

Then you can insert into the db:

```
include_once('../config/dbcon.php'); 
$query="INSERT INTO testeval (ave) VALUES ('$average')"; 
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

And finally retrieve it:

```
include_once('../config/dbcon.php'); 
$query="SELECT ave FROM testeval"; 
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$average = $row['ave'];
```

use the value:

```
<td><?php echo $average; ?> </td>
```

Comment: not very scalable that way. If you do it in PHP than you should fill the cells from an array and calculated the average by looping over the array and calculating the sum and then divide it by the array length.

Comment: Hi there sir amanga emmanuel, can you show me where to add the insert and retrieve code blocks, I not sure where to add that 2 part in my code

Comment: @tacoshy i what other way can i do the calculation?

Comment: @hirowii you can do the average calculation and insert in a seperate script then embed the script at the beginning of your current script. Then you can retrieve the `AVG` value in your current file since it will have already been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating in PHP, you can calculate in DB itself, which will minimize the roundtrips between PHP and DB.

The following example will suffice your requirement, but care to be take while inserting / updating the table. Do not insert / update without escaping the values if you are receiving the data from user.

```
<?php 
include('includes/header.php');
include_once('../config/dbcon.php');

// Change your query as shown below. this is very basic query, 
// you can improve this query to get column names dynamically.
$query="
SELECT 
   *, 
   (
    (q1+q2+q3+q4+q5+q6+q7+q8+q9+q10+q11+q12+q13+q14+q15+q16+q17+q18+q19+q20+q21+q22)/22 
   ) AS AVG 
FROM testeval";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query); 

?> 
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

    <head>

    <style>
    table, th, td{
        border: 3px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th{
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    td {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .title {
            max-width: 100%;
            margin: auto;
    }
    table {
        text-align= center;
         border: 1px;
        max-width= 1000px;
         line-height= 40px;
    }
    </style>

    </head> 

    <body class = "title"> 
    <table> 
    <form>
    <tr> 
    
        <th colspan="4"><h2>Evaluation Record</h2></th> 
        </tr> 

        <?php 

            
            while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        { 
        ?> 
            
            <tr>
              <th> ID: </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Name: </th>
              <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 1. Formulates/adopts objectives of the syllabus course learning outcomes. </th>
              <td><?php echo $row['q1']; ?> </td>
            <tr>
              <th> 2. Selects content and prepares appropriate instructional materials/teaching aids.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q2']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 3. Selects appropriate teaching methods/strategies.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q3']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 4. Relates new lesson with previous knowledge/skills.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q4']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 5. Conveys ideas clearly.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q5']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 6. Utilizes the art of questioning to develop higher level of thinking.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q6']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 7. Ensures students participation. </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q7']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 8. Shows mastery of the subject matter.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q8']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 9. Utilizes the blackboard or the learning management system of the college.  </th>
              <td><?php echo $row['q8']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 10. Creates assessments that are aligned with the syllabus course learning outcomes  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q10']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 11. Evaluates the attainment of the syllabus course learning outcomest.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q11']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 12. Maintains orderly classroom that is conducive to learning.  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q12']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 13. Decisiveness  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q13']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 14. Honesty / Integrity  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q14']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 15. Dedication / Commitment  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q15']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 16. Initiative / Resourcefulness  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q16']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 17. Courtesy  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q17']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 18. Human Relations  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q18']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 19. Leadership  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q19']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 20. Stress Toleranc  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q20']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 21. Fairness / Justice  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q21']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> 22. Proper Attire / Good Grooming  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['q22']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Average:   </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['AVG']; //<--CHANGE HERE THE AVG COLUMN NAME ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> Remarks:  </th> 
              <td><?php echo $row['message']; ?> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> <center> ------------------------------------------------------ </center> </th> 
              <td> <center> ------------------------------------------------------ </center> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th> <center> ------------------------------------------------------ </center> </th> 
              <td> <center> ------------------------------------------------------ </center> </td>
            </tr>

              
        </tr> 
        
        
        
    
        </tr> 
        </form>
    <?php 
          // You cannot insert the data into already existing row, 
          // in that case you have to UPDATE the row as below
          // (change primary key as per your db structure in `WHERE` condition).

           $query="UPDATE testeval SET ave = $row['AVG'] WHERE ID = $row['ID']"; 
           mysqli_query($con,$query);
      } 
     ?> 

    </table> 
    </body> 
    </html>

<?php include('includes/footer.php'); 

// IMPORTANT :- do not forget to close this connection and re-open when u require in other pages.
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much sir! your code works perfectly and now I have the calculation part done

Comment: You are welcome, please accept this answer by clicking the check mark. All the best.